Метод расширения для конкретного класса с дополнительной логикой в атрибуте
Я бы хотел присвоить атрибут к свойствам, Скорее всего это будет мой кастомный атрибут. И потом создать метод расширения который бы использовать логику этого атрибута.
    public class MyClass
    {
        [MyAttribute(MyEnum.Val1)]
        public decimal Property1 {get; set;}

        [MyAttribute(MyEnum.Val2)]
        public decimal Property2 {get; set;}

        public static string GetDecimalRoundString(this decimal property)
        {
            var attr = .GetCustomAttribute<MyAttribute>() // каким-то образом получаем атрибут
            switch (attr) {
            case MyEnum.Val1:
                return decimal.Round(property, 4, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString();
            break;
            case MyEnum.Val2:
                return decimal.Round(property, 4, MidpointRounding.ToEven).ToString();
            break;
            }
        }
    }

Чтобы потом вызывать его по свойству:
var myobj = new MyClass() { Property1 = 10 };
var str1 = myobj.Property1.GetDecimalRoundString();

Что-то вроде этого. Подскажите можно ли так сделать?
Будет ли это метод класса или метод расширения неважно. Цель - вызывать метод на свойство и не передавать лишних параметров так как метод будет вызываться часто на разные свойства.

Так, как вы хотите, сделать невозможно. В метод GetDecimalRoundString приходит значение, возвращаемое геттером, и у этого значения нету никакой информации о том, из какого свойства оно добыто.

@VladD понял, спасибо что подтвердили мои опасения, буду так же по старинке GetDecimalRoundString(Property1, MyEnum.Val1)

На основе атрибутов можно сгенерировать код, который прикрепит хитрую логику к вашему свойству. Но это достаточно сложный подход, вы получите намного меньше, чем затратите сил.

@VladD, а сделай пример с логикой, там же все равно будет decimal возвращаться, а не string?

Я думаю, тут можно поступить немного иначе. Сделайте метод расширения для классов, которому можно будет задать выражением нужное свойство, а там уже пойдет стандартная рефлексия. Скажем, что-то такое:
public static string GetDecimalRoundString<T, TProperty>(this T item, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> expression) where T : class
{
    var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
    var attribute = memberExpression.Member.GetCustomAttribute<MyAttribute>();
    var value = expression.Compile().Invoke(item);
    var decimalValue = Convert.ToDecimal(value);

    return attribute.Value switch
    {
        MyEnum.Val1 => decimal.Round(decimalValue, 4, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString(),
        MyEnum.Val2 => decimal.Round(decimalValue, 4, MidpointRounding.ToEven).ToString(),
        _ => value.ToString()
    };
}

Объяснять я думаю смысла нету, и так понятно, что да как.
P.S. Я тут специально не стал отлавливать ошибки и возиться с кастом в нужный тип динамически, не хотел нагружать пример.
Вызов тогда будет таким:
var result = myobj.GetDecimalRoundString(x=>x.Property1);

